# How to link the data set to the model in GCP

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to model for the first time in GCP and I cannot find nor figure out how I link the data to model on.  In my script, I would typically write read_csv from this path.

I get that I have to load it to Google Cloud Storage.  Its a csv and I'm running xgb classification over it.  The question is how to link those things so the script knowss to run it on that...

```
#read in the file
#ds

#model
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

y=ds[["Label_Num","ShotPlus"]]
y["Player"]=shots2["Player"]
#adjust in i
X=ds.drop(["ShotPlus", "Label_Num",
              #,"DSL_Available_Bandwidth","Band_2_DSL_rel","DSL_vals"
             ],axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train1,y_test1=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=785)

y_test = y_test1[["Label_Num"]]
y_train = y_train1[["Label_Num"]]

dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X_train,label=y_train)
dtest=xgb.DMatrix(X_test,label=y_test)
params={
        'max_depth':6,
    'min_child_weight': 4,
    'eta':0.1,
    'subsample': 0.8,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
#     "scale_pos_weight" : 8, #change me
    # Other parameters
#     'eval_metric' : "auc",
    'objective':'multi:softprob',
    "num_class":7,
    'seed':123
}
num_boost_round = 999
mod_addK=xgb.train(params,
             dtrain,
             num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
             evals=[(dtest, "Test")],
             early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

I haven't found examples which have been loaded as a CSV file.  [This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/ai-platform-unified/notebooks/official/custom/sdk-custom-image-classification-batch.ipynb) reads in a tf.dataset, [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/tabular-automl/dataset-train) tells me how it works for a process where I use the AutoML classification model.  But how does it work for a custom job where I have written my own code and want to tweak it?

The above code would be the task element of setting up my own source distribution, to which needs to be added the element to write it.  This I have lifted from the GCS page.

```
artifact_filename = 'ShotTypeModel.pkl'

# Save model artifact to local filesystem (doesn't persist)
local_path = artifact_filename
with open(local_path, 'wb') as model_file:
    pickle.dump(mod_addK, model_file)

# Upload model artifact to Cloud Storage
model_directory = os.environ['AIP_MODEL_DIR']
storage_path = os.path.join(model_directory, artifact_filename)
blob = storage.blob.Blob.from_string(storage_path, client=storage.Client())
blob.upload_from_filename(local_path)
```

There are a bunch of docs on the google website that sound like they should help, but don't give me specifics. Such as [using a managed dataset in a custom training app](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-managed-datasets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that the bucket gives a url and that is what you need to load the data.

You also need to include the package gcsfs to have this work.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import gcsfs
import pandas as pd
import pickle
#read in the file
print("Mod script starts")
ds = pd.read_csv("gs://shottypeids/ShotTypeModel_alldata.csv")
```